# Почему нельзя обратиться к атрибуту класса без явного имени класса внутри метода

Tags: python, python-3.x, атрибуты

Не могу понять, почему я не могу обратиться к атрибуту класса явно, не обращаясь к нему через пространство имен. Когда интерпретатор  видит объявление класса он создает пространство имен, в котором появляется 2 функции и одна переменная-name,так как функции и переменная находятся в одной локальной области видимости ,функции,если в них не предопределен name, могут обращаться к значению name, Но интерпретатор требует чтобы обращение было явным: MixedName.name. Почему так происходит?

```
class MixedName:
    name="privet"
    def __init__(self,value):
        self.ill=value
    def prt():
        print(name)


if __name__=="__main__":
    print(MixedName(10).prt())
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Поиск имени в Питоне упрощённо:

```
pylookup = ChainMap(locals(), globals(), vars(builtins))
```

то есть сперва локальное пространство имён просматривается (внутри метода имя ищется), затем глобальное (внутри модуля), затем во встроенных именах (типа len, str, range). Поэтому

```
def prt(self):
    print(name)
```

не найдёт `MixedName.name`:

```
>>> m = MixedName(10)
>>> m.prt()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 6, in prt
NameError: name 'name' is not defined
name 'name' is not defined
>>> import dis
>>> dis.dis(m.prt)
  6           0 LOAD_GLOBAL              0 (print)
              2 LOAD_GLOBAL              1 (name)
              4 CALL_FUNCTION            1
              6 POP_TOP
              8 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
             10 RETURN_VALUE
```

Видно, что `prt()` метод пытается найти глобальную переменную `name`.

Я сказал "упрощённо" выше, потому что Питон может обращаться к именам, локальным во внешних функциях:

```
>>> def outer():
...     def inner():
...         print(name)
...     name = 'value'
...     return inner
>>> outer()
<function outer.<locals>.inner at 0x7f8bd32f9730>
>>> outer()()
value
>>> dis.dis(outer())
  3           0 LOAD_GLOBAL              0 (print)
              2 LOAD_DEREF               0 (name)
              4 CALL_FUNCTION            1
              6 POP_TOP
              8 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
             10 RETURN_VALUE
```

здесь `name` не является локальным именем для `inner()` функции (closure). В этом смысле класс не является внешней функцией для методов в нём определённых. Чтобы обратиться к атрибуту класса следует или явно имя класса привести или воспользоваться самим экземпляром:

```
def prt(self):
    print(self.name)
```

Стоит явно упомянуть, что атрибут класса и экземпляра это разные вещи:

```
class C:
    attr = 1
    def __init__(self):
        self.attr = 2
    def print(self):
        print(C.attr, self.attr)

C().print()  # -> 1 2
```

Требование явно имя класса использовать является вполне в духе Питона: [«Явное лучше неявного»](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Python#.D0.A4.D0.B8.D0.BB.D0.BE.D1.81.D0.BE.D1.84.D0.B8.D1.8F): Питон требует явных импортов (`from pathlib import Path`), явного `self` и явного имени класса `MixedName.name`.

Answer (score 0):

**Я не понял что вы конкретно хотели, но мой совет в первую очередь изучите синтаксис языка...**

```
class MixedName:

    def __init__(self,value):
        self.name = "privet"
        self.value = value
        print(value)
    def prt(self):
        print(self.name)


if __name__=="__main__":
    mn = MixedName(10)
    print(mn.prt())
```

Comment: Сам собой, ваш вариант правильный, но я добивался совершенно другого, в моем случае name это атрибут класса, вы же определяете name как атрибут экземпляра.Проблема здесь совершенно в другом, мне не ясно, почему имя name будучи атрибутом класса не попадает в область видимости функции prt

Comment: Ключевое слово self как раз таки и определяет всё что находиться внутри класса, буду краток self говорит я внутри тебя класс и интерпретатор питон думает не иначе .....

Comment: `name` у вас не является атрибутом класса (у вас `name` это атрибут экземпляра).

Answer (score 0):

Думаю тут соображения, что раз есть понятный квалификатор (имя класса), то лучше его использовать для ясности. И так в обычных в функциях надо быть внимательным с областями видимости.

Comment: Просто мне не ясно, и модуль и класс являются пространствами имен,но в модуле функция сама находит переменную, а в классе же приходится почему-то указывать ее явно.Как по мне,это довольно странно.